# Javascript get decimal and thousands separator from NumberFormat

Tags: javascript, number-formatting

I'm looking for a method to get decimal and thousands separators from NumberFormat object.

```
var de = new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE');
```

Later I plan to use them to parse formated string back to Javascript's float. I know I could create sample number and then scan it with regex but I feel there must be some easier method to get those separators.

Comment: Are you sure you're not looking for [`toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)?

Answer (score 1):

Seems you can avoid doing the parsing yourself:

```
Intl.NumberFormat('de-CH').v8Parse(
    Intl.NumberFormat('de-CH').format(1000) // => 1'000
) // => 1000
```

But this sounds very chrome-specific :)

But if I were you I'd avoid parsing localized numbers represented as strings to numbers if I can.

Comment: Wow it would be very nice but we have to wait for wider browser support.

Comment: Yes it would be better not to parse strings to numbers but sometimes on client side we have to know what data user entered.

Answer (score 0):

Here the js function which will return formatted

```
function customNumberFormat( num){
    var parts = (''+ (num<0?-num:num)).split("."), s=parts[0], i=L= s.length, o='',c;
    while(i--){ o = (i==0?'':((L-i)%3?'':','))+s.charAt(i) +o }
    return (num<0?'-':'') + o + (parts[1] ? '.' + parts[1] : ''); 
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what this function does exactly?